# Add a random value between 1 and the difference between two other values to a list

Tags: r

I have generated a vector of random values:

```
> rand=sample(x=data$len, size = 1e6, replace =F)
> freads=rand[rand<8283][1:220];freads
  [1] 1340 1122 1523  282 1517 2086 1160  210 1140 1522 2039 1393  458 1785 1626 1017 1042  838 1753
 [20] 1471  244  574  471  861 1392 1520  806 2885  552 1627 1007 1277  553 1080 1377  429 1216  388
 [39] 1032  922 1546  538 1213 2076  807 1260  685  126 1461  450  587  418 1519 1610  999 2893 1099
 [58]  580 1454 1760 1513 1388 2872  455 1026 1984  860 2886 1087 1499 1646  615 1475  274 1350  967
 [77]  992 1301 1081  333  326  471 1845  595  912 1077 1598 1199 2892 1646 1070  956 1492  360  601
 [96] 1287 1928  373 1758 1729 1995  547 1661 1528 1159 1792  544  655 1659 1562  428 1123  456  376
[115]  632 2794 2907 1471 1661  910  901 2884 1169 1119 1639 1266 2892 1435 1256  908 1370  724 1064
[134] 1494 1022  358 1100 1147 1733 1324 2714 1627  558 1482  280 1229  263 1596 1671  539 1012  351
[153] 1486  858  469  739  513  553 2893 1381  723 1488 1192 1909  985 1447 1622 1482  748  743 1421
[172]  673 1065 1468  987 1113  609 1675  261 1675 1260 1085  326  769  185 1498 1596 1476 1531 1366
[191]  492 1050 1043  342  750  398  775 1015  636 1945 1323  585 1512 1457 1387 1050 1294 1150  383
[210] 1512  365  709 1377  244  415 1754 1131 1432 1339 1519
```

For each value `i` in `freads` I want to pick a random number between `1` and `8283-i`, and then I want to append that value to a new vector `begs`.

I have tried the following:

```
for(i in freads){
        nums=seq(1,8283-i,1)
        begs[i]=sample(x=nums,size=1,replace=F)
}
begs
```

The output is way longer than the length of `freads` and it contains a bunch of `NA`. The desired output should be a list of random integers that is the difference between `8283` and `freads[i]`, and it should also be the same length as `freads`.

I'm not great at for loops and I know its not what R is best used for. It would be great if there were an `apply` way to get this done. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over values of `freads` (`for(i in freads)`) which creates an issue when you store the value in `begs[i]`. Instead in your `for` loop you should iterate over index of `freads` value.

```
begs <- numeric(length(freads))
for(i in seq_along(freads)) {
  nums=seq(1, 8283 - freads[i],1)
  begs[i]=sample(x=nums,size=1,replace=F)
}
```

Using `sapply` you could write this as :

```
begs <- sapply(8283 - freads, function(i) sample(seq(1, i), 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ronak Shah. The for loop works great! But after playing around with the `sapply` solution a little, I think it should be this instead: `begs=sapply(freads,function(i) sample(seq(1,8283-i),1))`. Otherwise `max(begs+freads)` is greater than 8283. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I changed `sapply` code to `begs <- sapply(8283 - freads, function(i) sample(seq(1, i), 1))`. That works as expected?